# Limits of $\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$$
I tried to factor it but still nothing.

Comment: I edited it they way it seemed reasonable for me. Can you please elaborate on what do you know what you tried ("factor it" - what does it mean?)

Comment: Use a trig. identity on the denominator. Then cancel like terms and then evaluate as theta goes to pi.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)} = \frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{1-\cos^2(\theta)} = \frac{1}{1-\cos(\theta)} $$

Comment: Just use $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ and $ 1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$ to show this result.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $x=\pi-2y$

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1+\cos(\pi-2y)}{\sin^2(\pi-2y)}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\cos2y}{\sin^22y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2\sin^2y}{(2\sin y\cos y)^2}$$

We can cancel out $\sin y$ from the numerator & the denominator as $y\to0,\sin y\to0\implies\sin y\ne0$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

$sin ^2\theta=1-cos^2\theta$
the expression will become $\frac{(1+cos \theta)}{1-cos^2\theta}$

$\implies \frac{1}{1-cos \theta}$

as $\theta$ approaches $\pi$ this becomes $$\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$